# Twilio Chat API, getUnconsumedMessagesCount always 0

Tags: javascript, angular, twilio, twilio-api

I'm trying to get the number of messages unread for a specific member in a specific channel. To do this I was hoping to use **channel.getUnconsumedMessagesCount()** as defined in the [documentation](https://media.twiliocdn.com/sdk/js/chat/releases/0.11.1/docs/Channel.html#getUnconsumedMessagesCount__anchor).

```
myChannel.join()
  .then(function(c) {
    console.log('Joined channel ' + c.sid);
    return myChannel.getUnconsumedMessagesCount();
  })
  .then(m => {
    console.log('current count unread: ' + m);
  });
```

The unread count always return 0. To test, I do the following:

1. user 2 submitting a message to myChannel in another chrome tab
2. user 2 myChannel get's updated with the message from (1) via
   .on('messageAdded', [...])
3. refresh user 1 chrome tab, and get getUnconsumedMessagesCount with
   value of 0
4. If I call myChannel.getMessages() for user1, I see the message from user2

Initially I called .getUnconsumedMessagesCount() without doing join() first, I thought this could be the issue, but even with join still nothing.

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply here. I can't see anything you've done wrong here, so it might be an issue on the Twilio side. I recommend getting in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and sending them the details, including the Chat Service SID that you're using.

Comment: Support ... oh no :/ Alright, thx.

Answer (score 5):

before you can get UnconsumedMessagesCount you need **manually set last read message** ([Send a Consumption Report](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/chat/guides/consumption-horizon#message-read-status))

something like this (JS)

```
 channel.getMessages(1).then(function (messages) {
    var last_message_index = messages.items[0].index;
    channel.updateLastConsumedMessageIndex(last_message_index);
 });
```

Answer (score 4):

I am having the same issue with the javascript SDK where it always returns 0.

I ended up doing the following which is working

```
const count = channel.getMessagesCount();
const unreadCount = channel.lastConsumedMessageIndex === null ? count : count - channel.lastConsumedMessageIndex - 1
```

I also noticed that using any of the functions to set the messages consumed can take up to a full minute before actually returning that information in the channel.lastConsumedMessageIndex